# DotNetOpenAuth SignInWithTwitter sample doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I use DotNetOpenAuth 3.4.7 with valid consumer key and secret. When I try to sign in with twitter on localhost (\Samples\OAuthConsumer\SignInWithTwitter.aspx) it crashes with following exception.

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Source Error: 


Line 190:           }
Line 191:           Uri callback = MessagingUtilities.GetRequestUrlFromContext().StripQueryArgumentsWithPrefix("oauth_");
Line 192:           var request = TwitterSignIn.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(callback, null, redirectParameters);
Line 193:           return TwitterSignIn.Channel.PrepareResponse(request);
Line 194:       }

Source File: C:\Users\Andrey\Downloads\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.7.11121\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.7.11121\Samples\DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock\TwitterConsumer.cs    Line: 192
```

TwitterConsumer latest update is Mar 07, 2010. (https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/v3.4/samples/DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock/TwitterConsumer.cs)

Is this sample still alive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's my bad. I didn't specify the callback url in app profile.

Comment: I have the same issue? I am specifying the callback url but still get this error?